# TimeStamp as key and byte[]s as arraylist in a hashmap

Tags: java, datetime, arraylist, hashmap, arrays

I have a problem statement in which I have to store every `byte[]` against the time it was obtained.

I thought I could use a hashmap where the key would be the timestamp and the value could be a list of the `byte[]`. The timestamp is calculated using Gregorian calendar with the arguments of year, month, date, hour and mins. The output given is time in milliseconds. The `byte[]` is observed to be received every nanosecond. So all the `byte[]`s obtained in a particular min, would be stored in a list.

Every time a `byte[]` is obtained, the key, i.e. the timestamp would first be checked if it exists, if it does, the list for that key is where the `byte[]` would be added. If the key does not exist, which would happen when the minute or the hour changes, a new key again is created wrt timestamp and also a new list is created and now in this list the `byte[]` received at that min would be added.

Can someone please tell me how do I put all of this into code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are here to help with specific programming problems, not to write your entire code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Long` containing the timestamp as key to the hash and when you add a new `byte[]` you retrieve the corresponding list to which you add the new `byte[]` for that timestamp.

The exception is when a key has no list stored yet in the hash, you create a new list and add it to the hash before you fall through to adding the `byte[]` to the list.